# why is typescript not throwing error for this?

Tags: typescript

why i dont have an error in this code eventho the module ./one do not export myDefaultExport
and even in my declare module am not exporting myDefaultExport so why i can import it without error

```
import { test,myDefaultExport,MyType } from "./one";

declare module './one' {
    export type MyType = number
    export type MyDefaultType = {a: string}
    export let myExport: MyType
    let myDefaultExport: MyDefaultType
    
   }

myDefaultExport.a="7"
console.log(myDefaultExport.a)
```